# How to create a temp sqlite databse for best testing with mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a small Node app with API routes written in express. These routes subsequently call different functions to perform CRUD on a sqlite database. I want to use mocha to test this app and I'm very new to testing. I want some recommendations on how to approach this.

Some questions I have:

1. For unit testings, should I just test the functions the routes call? Or both the functions and the actual routes?
2. I need to create a dummy test db for testing purposes that only runs when I use the test script. So in my test dir, should I just create a new sqlite db that only runs when I run the script?
3. How do I create a temp sqlite db that will be gone after running the tests? Should I just create a temp table instead of a temp db?

Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0):

answer for Q1: In mocha test you can both test : unit test or functional test and routing test with sending `http` requset. But the point is that you have a database and the requests are asynchronous. In the meantime you will have to use another auxiliary module called `Chai` to get the output.

please read this link for write a correct test : [A quick and complete guide to Mocha testing](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-quick-and-complete-guide-to-mocha-testing-d0e0ea09f09d/)

answer for Q2 & Q3: Experience has shown that developers need to use several different configurations for database testing environments. For example development environment, test environment, production environment and ...
In this case, you have the data of each environment and can compare it to the next and draw the flaws and errors.

If you are also interested in dummy test db environments, you should create your database and schema with command and scripts. finally delete them again with the same commands. [SQLite Create, Alter, Drop Table](https://www.guru99.com/sqlite-create-alter-drop-table.html)